# How to delete records in hibernate one to many relationship

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

I have two tables, one is QuickLinks and another is OrgUnit. OrgUnit table is Parent and QuickLinks table is child. I have added relationship in QuickLinks table as Many to One.

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="TBL_STD_QUICK_LINKS")
public class QuickLinks {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "FLD_QUICK_LINK_ID")
    private Long quickLinkId;

    @Column(name = "FLD_DISPLAY_NAME")
    private String displayName;

    @ManyToOne
    private OrgUnit orgUnit; 
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_STD_ORG_UNIT")
public class OrgUnit implements Serializable  {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "FLD_ORGUNIT_ID")
private Long orgUnitId;

@Column(name = "FLD_OUNAME")
private String ouName;

@Column(name = "FLD_OUPARENT_ID")
private Long ouParentId;

@Column(name = "FLD_OUPATH")
private String ouPath;

}
```

I want to delete records QuickLinks table , who's FLD_OUPATH from OrgUnit starts with '/abc/xyz'.

```
Query executeQuery = getSession().createQuery("delete from QuickLinks as links where links.orgUnit.ouPath like :OrgName");
 executeQuery.setParameter("OrgName", ouPath+"%");
 executeQuery.executeUpdate();
```

but I am getting exceptions while executing this query.
So can anyone tell me what is wrong in it.?

Comment: What exceptions? Post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch15.html#batch-direct):

> No forms of join syntax, either implicit or explicit, can be specified in a bulk HQL query. Sub-queries can be used in the where-clause, where the subqueries themselves may contain joins.

```
links.orgUnit
```

is an implicit inner join, and is thus not acceptable.

You could use a native (SQL) query. Or, as the documentation hints, you could use a subquery:

```
delete from QuickLinks as link where link.id in 
    (select link2.id from QuickLinks link2 
     where link2.orgUnit.ouPath like :orgName)
```

Side note: `QuickLinks` should be named `QuickLink`.